# Python - OpenCV Normalization of Array or NumPy Operation to Match 2 Image Arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have two Images that I want to match the Min and Max values of:

- Image1 has a Min val of 40, and a Max val of 220
- Image2 has a Min val of 80, and a Max val of 180

What's the best way to "normalize" or stretch Image2 so that it matches the value range of Image2 so that it matches the value range of Image1?

Is there a OpenCV normalize function that will do this? Or a NumPy function that will stretch/expand my array? (Or a better option?)

Comment: cv2.normalize() or better skimage exposure.rescale_intensity()

Comment: @fmw42 I'll look into skimage - Which cv2.normalize function were you thinking? I'm only familiar with norm_minmax - doesn't that normalize your alpha and beta over a 0-255 range? (I want my range to be limited (I.e. Image1 range))

Comment: Using [cv2.normalize](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) you can provide alpha and beta for minimal and maximal values

Comment: skimage exposure.rescale_intensity() allows you to specify input and output ranges. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity